# PHP Mysqli foreach not pulling data

Tags: php, foreach, mysqli

I have got the following PHP that sites inside `<script>` tags and I am trying to get it to pull data from my table `map` using `mysqli`

But in console.log it shows up the following `position: new google.maps.LatLng(, ),`

I'm unsure where I have went wrong in my code. My database connection is live and inside the variable `$con`

**PHP**

```
  <?php 
  $count = 0;
  $rowset = $con->query("SELECT * FROM map");
  foreach ($rowset as $row): ?>
  add_marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row->lat ?>, <?php echo $row->lng ?>),
        title:<?php echo $row->location ?>,
        map:map
    });
  <?php 
  $count++;
  endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does $con->query exactly do ? Just run the query or give back an object with results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not pulling the data. Replace the foreach line with this:

```
while ($row = $rowset->fetch_object()):
```

That should do it.

Edit:
Don't forget to replace `endforach;` with `endwhile;`